# create function inside my model method not working for my rails 5 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app that uses that party code that i wrote and is located in my lib directory of my rails application.The code generates data that is supposed to generate data that is supposed to be saved to the db but when the create function is triggered it triggers nil results... the error from the code when the code is run from the rails console is as shown below:

```
2.3.3 :004 > Plag.scrap('http://watabelabs.com')
scrapping http://watabelabs.com for data...
crawling the web...
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => #<Plag id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, url: "http://watabelabs.com", content: "How can we help?", filename: "watabelabs_com.txt", user_id: nil, doc_id: nil> 
2.3.3 :005 > Plag.all
  Plag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "plags".* FROM "plags"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> 
2.3.3 :006 > Plag.count
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "plags"
 => 0
```

The code in my model is this:

```
def self.scrap(url)
  result = @anemon.scrap(url)
  Plag.create({url: result[:url], content: result[:content], filename: result[:filename]}) if result
end
```

The code in my lib directory that generates the data to be stored in the db is this:
` def crawl_and_scrap(url)

```
  filename = url.gsub("http://", "").split(".").join("_").strip + ".txt"

  #crawl the web to get information out web pages
      puts "crawling the web..."

      Anemone.crawl(url) do |anemone|
        anemone.on_every_page do |page|
          @urls = []
          @urls << page.url

        end
      end
  #feed in the urls obtained from the crawl to start scrapping  
      puts "scrapping #{url} for data..."

      data = []

      @urls.each do |urli|
        html_data = open(urli).read
        nokogiri_object = Nokogiri::HTML(html_data)
        elements = nokogiri_object.xpath("//p","//h1","//h2","//h3","//h4","//h5","//h6")

        elements.each do |element|
          data << element.text
        end
      end
    write_to_file(url, data)
    #store_visited_link(url)
    # in ruby the last statement in a method is always the returned value
    # of the particular method
    {:url => url, :content => data , :filename => filename}


end `
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: please share your strong params declaration for `{url: result[:url], content: result[:content], filename: result[:filename]}` from your controller. Usually the DB performs a roll back if some mandatory fields are missing. If you are not declaring strong params and permitting those fields, then they will be empty, like it show in your console create action. All the fields are empty. `#<Plag id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, url: "http://watabelabs.com", content: "How can we help?", filename: "watabelabs_com.txt", user_id: nil, doc_id: nil>`

Comment: `2.3.3 :001 > Plag.crawl_and_scrap("http://watabelabs.com")
crawling the web...
scrapping http://watabelabs.com for data...
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Doc must exist, User must exist `

Comment: This is the error when i use  ` create!  ` instead .There is a relationship between Plag model and User  and Doc model...immediately the scrap is over it saves automatically to the db...Don't know anyway to add the user id and doc id to the db alongside or before hand

Comment: Im doing this from the rails console directly ... i don't have anything in my controller yet as i am still testing the code.

Comment: Is that the error message? Do you think we could have more details with `plag = Plag.craw..` etc and `plag.erros.full_messages`? As I wrote in my message. Rollback is connected to missing parameters, usually parameters that are foreign keys are mandatory like `Doc_id` and `user_id`. You call `self.scrap(url)` and from `url` they obtain all the parameters. Are you sure that you do not need to define them as `strong_params`. If not, could you tell us more about those parameters? Thanks

Comment: You can create Strong Params in your console. `params = ActiveController::Parameters.new()` between () you need to include the parameters, then you need to call .permit to permit those parameters. You can read detailed informations in the following API http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

Comment: Search for Doc_id and user_id in the github documentation

Comment: `2.3.3 :001 > params = ActionController::Parameters.new(user_id: 1 ,doc_id: 1)
 => <ActionController::Parameters {"user_id"=>1, "doc_id"=>1} permitted: false> 
2.3.3 :002 > params.permit
 => <ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: true> 
2.3.3 :003 >` done this but still need to make the user_id and the doc_id save into the db when i do `Plag.crawl_and_scrap("http://watabelabs.com")`

Comment: a user and a documents with those ids already exist in their respective tables

Comment: So this is third party code? is there documentation somewhere that I can read? What is the name and the website? Is this a gem?

Comment: http://anemone.rubyforge.org/information-and-examples.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it says: **rollback transaction**, it definitely means that the model isn't valid that you are going to create.

There are multiple ways to solve this problem: You can use [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) to debug the code, and check for `plag.errors.full_messages` where `plag` being the instance.

You may also use `create!` instead of `create`, as the method `create!` will throw an exception if the model values aren't the valid ones.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code from your console.
If you notice, when you call the method in the console, it performs a query to create an object and try to save it to the database. As we discussed in the chat the two last fields `user_id` and `doc_id` are empty.

```
<Plag id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, url: "http://watabelabs.com", content: "How can we help?", filename: "watabelabs_com.txt", user_id: nil, doc_id: nil>
```

This is the method. The method saves the `result` of the `.scrap()` method and uses the `result` variable as input for `Plag.create()`.
If you watch at your `Plag.create()` it misses two parameters `result[:user_id]` and `result[:doc_id]`. I say this because it uses the same parameters for the `result[:url]` with url, `result[:content]` with content ... etc..

You need to set a breakpoint as shown below and inspect the result variant, so that you can correctly feed the `Plag.create`.

```
def self.scrap(url)
  result = @anemon.scrap(url)
  binding.pry # inspect the result variant
  Plag.create({url: result[:url], content: result[:content], filename: result[:filename]}) if result
end
```

I am quoting the documentation

> Interacting with Pages
>
> Any URL that Anemone finds in an  tag's HREF attribute is considered a page, and represented by an instance of the Page class. A page might not be an HTML document; it could be an RSS feed, an image, etc.
>
> Each Page object stores several pieces of information:

```
url - The URL of the page
aliases - Other URLs that redirected to this page, or the Page that this one redirects to
headers - The full HTTP response headers
code - The HTTP response code (e.g. 200, 301, 404)
body - The raw HTTP response body
doc - A Nokogiri::HTML::Document of the page body (if applicable)
links - An Array of all the URLs found on the page that point to the same domain
```

> For your convenience, each Page also has a data attribute, which is an OpenStruct for storing any data you wish to associate with a Page, such as title, meta-description, etc.
>
> Here is an example of using Anemone to print a sorted list of all page titles on a site:

```
Anemone.crawl("http://www.example.com/") do |anemone|
  titles = []
  anemone.on_every_page { |page| titles.push page.doc.at('title').inner_html rescue nil }
  anemone.after_crawl { puts titles.compact.sort }
end
```

Comment: Thanks...This took a while but reading the anemone documentation really helped..Most appreciated Fabrizio.